# SequelizeJS - Invalid models?

Tags: sequelize.js, hapi.js

I have defined some models for Sequelize, and when I start my server, I get errors for all of the models.

```
user.js is not a valid model
```

Here's my model definition;

```
'use strict';
 module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
   var User = sequelize.define('User', {
     id: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
     emailAddress: DataTypes.STRING,
     firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
     lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
     mobileNumber: DataTypes.STRING,
     joinDate: DataTypes.DATE,
     emailConfirmed: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
     accessLevel: DataTypes.INT,
     active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
}, {
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {

  }
 }
});
return User;
};
```

To generate the models I used sequelize-cli, so I am not sure why they are invalid. I am using the [hapi-sequelize](https://github.com/danecando/hapi-sequelize) plugin to make Sequelize work with HapiJS.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue ?

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab I am! So much so that I abandoned trying to figure out Sequelize that I started to use Bookshelf, but I don't fully understand Bookshelf yet so I'm open to returning to Sequelize!

Comment: FYI I have since changed INT to INTEGER and the error persists. This also happens for models without INTEGER fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this question in the future;

The issue with this code is this line;

```
accessLevel: DataTypes.INT,
```

it should be;

```
accessLevel: DataTypes.INTEGER,
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are reporting showed on my side only when I was including models directory which has an `index.js` file that is used to load the models from the DB and is not a proper model js file for sequalize to read from.

I did `sequalize init` setup my config inside `config/config.json` with the proper credentials.

Then I created a user model through the CLI, and migrated to load it in the database `sequelize db:migrate`

below is my configuration:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "database": "nodedb",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
}
```

Then I registered sequalize with Hapi as follows, note that I am asking the sequalize hapi plugin to load models from a subdirectory inside the models one so it wont read that `index.js`:

```
'use strict';

var Hapi = require('hapi');

// Create a server with a host and port
var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8000,
});

server.register(
    [
        {
            register: require('hapi-sequelize'),
            options: {
                database: 'nodedb',
                user: 'root',
                pass: 'root',
                dialect: 'mysql',
                port: 3306,
                models: 'models/models/*.js',
                sequelize: {
                    define: {
                        underscoredAll: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    ], function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('failed to load plugin');
        }

        // Start the server
        server.start((err) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }

          console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
        });
    }
);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Rabee, it looks like you might be correct. I really appreciate your effort, thank you very much. I will implement in the same way when I get home and report back!